# converting ValueType to BigInteger threw exception: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, biginteger, value-type

Following the MSDN example of
[ValueType Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype?view=net-6.0) on this lines

```
  // Use BigInteger as common integral type
  if (IsInteger(value1) && IsInteger(value2)) {

     BigInteger bigint1 = (BigInteger) value1; // threw exception: System.InvalidCastException
     BigInteger bigint2 = (BigInteger) value2; // threw exception: System.InvalidCastException

     return (NumericRelationship) BigInteger.Compare(bigint1, bigint2);
  }
```

the cast to BigInteger throws **System.InvalidCastException** Specified cast is not valid.

If I add on the example, a line that make the code pass from there, I got the exception.

```
public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", 19, Utility.Compare(19, 19), 19);
   }
}
```

On IL code I see that its just make unboxing, as the ValueType is an object... and not convert the number to BigInteger.

So is this a bug, is this something that I don't understand?

**How to convert a ValueType to BigInteger ?**

Of course one way is this:

```
public static BigInteger ConvertToBigInteger(ValueType value)
{
    if (value is Int32)
        return new BigInteger((Int32)value);

    if (value is Int16)
        return new BigInteger((Int16)value);

    if (value is Int64)
        return new BigInteger((Int64)value);

    if (value is Byte)
        return new BigInteger((Byte)value);

    if (value is UInt32)
        return new BigInteger((UInt32)value);

    if (value is UInt16)
        return new BigInteger((UInt16)value);

    if (value is UInt64)
        return new BigInteger((UInt64)value);

    if (value is SByte)
        return new BigInteger((SByte)value);

    return (BigInteger)value;
}
```

### on dotnetfiddle.net

The code from MSDN to **dotnetfiddle.net** with the extra line that make it pass from the part that's throw the exception
https://dotnetfiddle.net/oyaVvm

The same code with the convert I mention https://dotnetfiddle.net/kN7iNA   is working

Answer (score 0):

```
// Just an example that caters for Int64
public static BigInteger toBigInt(ValueType value)
{   
    BigInteger response = Convert.ToInt64(value);
    return response;
}
```

**Update:**
I updated your dotnet fiddle to cater for your unsigned value with a catch all to work off of the string constructor.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/jNHBo2

```
public static BigInteger toBigInt(ValueType value)
{   
    BigInteger response;
    if(value is Int64)
        response = Convert.ToInt64(value);
    else if (value is UInt64)
        response = Convert.ToUInt64(value);
    else 
        response = BigInteger.Parse(value.ToString());
    return response;
}
```

Comment: if its unsigned ? `UInt64` ?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to use that conversion if the value is unsigned.

Comment: still is not `BigInteger`...

Comment: Have you tried this? It will convert your numeric ValueType to a BigInteger as you originally asked in this post.

public static BigInteger toBigInt(ValueType value)
{ 
 BigInteger response = Convert.ToInt64(value);
 return response;
}

Comment: this is fails if its UInt64, and larger than the Int64 max value check this -> https://dotnetfiddle.net/ixVBah

Comment: The same example with the convert that I have above works -> https://dotnetfiddle.net/aCm3sY

however my main issue is that the example code on MSDN is not working -

Comment: Sure, but you just copied my function as is without detecting the input value to determine if it is an unsigned value. This was just an example, if you checked the type to see if it is unsigned then you'd convert using the ToUInt64 method. The trouble is the BigInt constructor does not support implicit casting from a ValueType object. You either need to convert to a supported type or if your value is large then parse a string representation.

Comment: You'll need to clear about your intention as the title of this post focused on an invalid cast exception. I can see that there is a conflict with the MSDN example code, I'm just trying to offer a solution.

Comment: thank you Nicholas, the main problem is "how to compare numbers of different types that are stored to an object" - because if you use for example a dictionary<object, > and you add numbers there, if the numbers are different type is confuzed

Comment: Perhaps BigInteger.Parse will provide the most robust/generic option. Check my updated .NET Fiddle.

Comment: thank you again. I want to avoid to convert it to string because is "too slow". The simples way to see if they are the same is to covert them both to string... The hole think is a fast find of numbers inside a dictionary<>, something like indexing on a database... and to do that is to add them to number valueType of bigInteger, but the convert of the c# just not works if you pass a general valueType...

Comment: If performance if your goal, then you'll need to use explicit code to detect the underlying type and convert/cast accordingly. You'll need to compare the performance between explicit casts and convert and what the base type of the value is before it is added to your collection; I think you'll find it is the same outcome. 
The problem as we've both stated is that the BigInteger constructor does not support ValueTypes.  FYI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert?view=net-6.0#conversions-to-and-from-base-types

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try.

```
BigInteger bigint1 = new BigInteger((int)value1);
BigInteger bigint2 = new BigInteger((int)value2);
```

Comment: please add this line : `Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", 19, Utility.Compare(19, 19), 19);` because is not pass that part of code I mention.

Comment: The code on the example, forgot to pass all the lines for check if its works or not...

Comment: Please look at my updated answer.

Comment: the value is not Int, can be any type - you are not see the code in depth and you are rush to answer.... please see again the example step by step... especial the function `IsInteger()` The purpose of the code `is to compare different types of numbers`  (not the same int)

Comment: right, but both values have to be an `integral` type in order to enter that `if` block. Couldn't any of those types be cast to an int before being passed to the `BigInteger` constructor?